# Is it possible to extract Coordinates of Polygon Centroid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, centroids

I have created polygon centroids using one of the "Geometry Tools" but I would like to extract the actual coordinates into Excel for further work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

Create 2 new columns (x and y) type real. In field calculator use option update existing field and execute following expressions: `$x` (for x column) and `$y` (for y column). Actually you can create new columns in field calculator directly using create new column option. Now you can export your layer as CSV (save layer as) and work with it in Excell or whatever you like.

Comment: Superb, easy when you know how!

Comment: @BNA, if your issue was solved (and you are satisfied with the answer), please mark my answer as "accepted" (transparent mark under votes counter of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a lazy way of getting the coordinates.

1. Select all features in the centroids layer using selection tools.
2. Press Ctrl+C to copy it to clipboard.
3. Open Excel. Press Ctrl+V to paste data to clipboard.

You get the [Well Known Text(WKT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) of the features in the `'wkt_geom'` field in Excel as shown below. This is a great way to pull the WKTs out of features.

[image]

Comment: For this case I prefer the method used by @ss-rebelious, but it's still a very good hint to know, thanks!